# Exclusive rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a path `a/<SEGMENT>` where segment is anything but `x` or `y`. How do I do this in nginx? In Apache, I would do this by following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/x
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/y
RewriteRule ^a/(.+)$ script.php
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general nginx will try to match the most specific location first. So if /a/x or /a/y is not matched, the default location / will be matched:

```
location / {
    try_files /script.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ ^/a/(?:x|y) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```